# Decode Base64 within Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, base64

| key | value | topic | partition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | `dGVzdF90ZXh0` | Topic.Name | 0 |
| null | `dGVzdF90ZXh0` | Topic.Name | 0 |
| null | `dGVzdF90ZXh0` | Topic.Name | 0 |

`df_1`

I have a Spark dataframe where the column `value` is a Base64 encoded. I would like to be able to add a column at the end of the dataframe with an unencoded version of it.

```
import base64

df_2 = df_1.withColumn('unencoded_base64',base64.b64decode(df_1.value))
```

The above code gives me the error:

```
TypeError: a2b_base64() argument 1 must be convertible to a buffer, not Column
```

Comment: You can try using `udf` which can do the decoding and then add the result as a column.

Comment: Same can we do in Spark SQL? I have same requirement in Spark SQL.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484508/manipulating-single-value-of-a-key-inside-map-struct-in-spark-sql-from-multiple

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [unbase64](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#unbase64(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) inbuilt function for that

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unbase64
df_2 = df_1.withColumn('unencoded_base64', unbase64(df_1.value))
```

which should give you

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+
|key |value       |topic     |partition|unencoded_base64            |
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+
|null|dGVzdF90ZXh0|Topic.Name|0        |[74 65 73 74 5F 74 65 78 74]|
|null|dGVzdF90ZXh0|Topic.Name|0        |[74 65 73 74 5F 74 65 78 74]|
|null|dGVzdF90ZXh0|Topic.Name|0        |[74 65 73 74 5F 74 65 78 74]|
+----+------------+----------+---------+----------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 7):

adding to Remesh's answer, you need to cast it to string to get it in "readable" context -

```
df_2=df_1.withColumn('unencoded_base64',unbase64(df_1.value).cast("string"))
```