# how to decrypt base64 column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, encryption, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a column encrypted, and I want to decrypt the column and put it into a new column. Below is my codes:

```
def decrypt(trace_info: str):
   msg = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(trace_info)
   ...
   return trace_info_decrpt

df = df.withColumn('new column name', decrypt(col('encrypt'))
```

the type of the param of the function `decrypt` is string, obviously there will be a param type mismatch error.. so, how can I convert `col('encrypt')` into string ?
or is there any other way to decrypt the column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode Base64 within Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421059/decode-base64-within-spark-dataframe)

Comment: pyspark  base64.unbase64() could not decode the column value.  Is there any functions in pyspark equal to "base64.urlsafe_b64decode"?

Comment: What is the schema of your input `df` dataframe ? You can get it by calling [`df.printSchema()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.printSchema.html) and add it to your question